# Spring/JPA app searching for non-existent database table

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a Spring application using JPA as the ORM, I think that's correct, and Swagger to create a nice UI for my endpoints.

When trying to make a POST or PUT request with data that has already been saved in the database I am receiving an error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/api/orgchart] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'orgchart_api.employee_department' doesn't exist
```

It's pretty obvious that the error is coming from the fact that JPA is attempting to update this data on the `employee_department` table and that this table does not exist. The problem I'm having is figuring out **WHY** JPA is trying to access that table.

Data flow:

## Swagger UI -> POST Request with JSON

```
  {
    "id": 104,
    "isActive": true,
    "manager": null,
    "firstName": "string",
    "middleInitial": null,
    "lastName": "string",
    "department": {
      "id": 104,
      "isActive": true,
      "parentDepartment": {
        "id": 101,
        "isActive": true,
        "parentDepartment": null,
        "manager": null,
        "name": "Marketing"
      },
      "manager": null,
      "name": "Americas"
    },
    "jobTitle": {
      "id": 1001,
      "isActive": true,
      "name": "Jr. Developer"
    },
    "email": "e",
    "skypeName": "e",
    "isManager": false
  }
```

## -> EmployeeController

```
package com.orgchart.web.controller;

import com.orgchart.model.Employee;
import com.orgchart.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/emps")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
    public Employee createOrUpdateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeService.storeOrUpdate(employee);
    }

}
```

## -> EmployeeService

```
package com.nexient.orgchart.service;

import com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity.DepartmentEntity;
import com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity.EmployeeEntity;
import com.nexient.orgchart.data.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.nexient.orgchart.mapper.EmployeeMapper;
import com.nexient.orgchart.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    public Employee storeOrUpdate(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = employeeMapper.modelToEntity(employee);
        EmployeeEntity savedEmployeeEntity = employeeRepository.save(employeeEntity);
        Employee employeeModel = employeeMapper.entityToModel(savedEmployeeEntity);
        return employeeModel;
    }
```

## -> EmployeeMapper

```
package com.nexient.orgchart.mapper;

import com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity.DepartmentEntity;
import com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity.EmployeeEntity;
import com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity.JobTitleEntity;
import com.nexient.orgchart.model.Department;
import com.nexient.orgchart.model.Employee;
import com.nexient.orgchart.model.JobTitle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@Component
public class EmployeeMapper implements EntityModelMapper<EmployeeEntity, Employee> {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentMapper departmentMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JobTitleMapper jobTitleMapper;

    @Override
    public EmployeeEntity modelToEntity(Employee employee) {
        Assert.notNull(employee, "Employee model cannot be null.");

        EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = new EmployeeEntity();
        DepartmentEntity departmentEntity = departmentMapper.modelToEntity(employee.getDepartment());
        JobTitleEntity jobTitleEntity = jobTitleMapper.modelToEntity(employee.getJobTitle());
        Employee employeeManager = employee.getManager();

        if (employeeManager != null) {
            EmployeeEntity employeeManagerEntity = modelToEntity(employeeManager);
            employeeEntity.setManager(employeeManagerEntity);
        }

        employeeEntity.setId(employee.getId());
        employeeEntity.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
        employeeEntity.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
        employeeEntity.setMiddleInitial(employee.getMiddleInitial());
        employeeEntity.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
        employeeEntity.setDepartment(departmentEntity);
        employeeEntity.setJobTitle(jobTitleEntity);
        employeeEntity.setIsManager(employee.getIsManager());
        employeeEntity.setSkypeName(employee.getSkypeName());
        employeeEntity.setIsActive(employee.getIsActive());

        return employeeEntity;
    }
```

From here it just runs through the other `<Model>.modelToEntity()` for `jobTitle` and `department` and eventually calls the `employeeRepository.save(employeeEntity)` from the **EmployeeService** file which is where the error is coming from.

To reiterate, why is my POST request attempting to access the `employee_department` table when I haven't specified it as a table name in any of my entities?

## Entities

### EmployeeEntity

```
package com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_initial")
    private Character middleInitial;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "skype_name")
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String skypeName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_title_id")
    private JobTitleEntity jobTitle;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private EmployeeEntity manager;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private DepartmentEntity department;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private Set<EmployeeEntity> ManagedEmployees;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<DepartmentEntity> ManagedDepartments;

    @Column(name = "is_manager")
    @NotNull
    private boolean isManager;

    ... Getters and Setters ...
```

### JobTitleEntity

```
package com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "job_title")
public class JobTitleEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<EmployeeEntity> titleEmployees;

    ... Getters and Setters ...
```

### DepartmentEntity

```
package com.nexient.orgchart.data.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class DepartmentEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private EmployeeEntity manager;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_department_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private DepartmentEntity parentDepartment;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDepartment")
    private Set<DepartmentEntity> departments = new HashSet<>(0);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<EmployeeEntity> employees = new HashSet<>(0);

    ... Getters and Setters ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have a `N` employee to `1` department relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private DepartmentEntity department;
```

Your JPA implementation chooses to back this relation using a dedicated table instead of a nullable column. It has apparently derived the `employee_department` name for this automatically from the table names for the entities involved.

It will probably prove to be quite revealing to run your application with your JPA implementation configured to generate DDL statements and to log all SQL statements. The exact configuration will depend on your chosen JPA provider but since you are using Spring you will likely need `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Do you know how I can prevent this from happening or would it be better to let create this table? My POST seems to work for a moment and then bugs out with this error after a few requests. The only way I've been able to fix it so far is to reset my database and the server.

Comment: To "prevent" this from happening you must effectively cede the point and manually define an `Entity` that replaces the original relationship/mapping.  This also implies a breaking change to the rest of your code: you will need additional repositories to retrace the relationship. Fighting your JPA provider to change its behaviour/its expectations is definitely not a good idea. Better to adjust however you set up your database to include the necessary tables for your relations.